# Web method exception throws just a text

Tags: .net, web-services, exception, .net-3.5, webmethod

I have a web method and when i throw soapexception or faultexception it shows just as a text with custom errors=on in web.config, or with text and row where it occurred with  custom errors=off. There is now XML formatting of the error. Tough standard string output of webmethod is returned fine in formated XML.

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Downloads file from SP and saves it to DB")]
public string SaveFileFromSPToDb(string siteGuid, string webGuid, string listGuid, string itemId, string fileUrl)
{
    throw new SoapException("exception test", SoapException.ServerFaultCode);
}
```

What can be the cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could return your own struct instead of a string, and give that struct both your return type and a exception object that is set to null if nothing went wrong.